# Modify / Enhance YouTube tutorial to play video internally

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube, android-youtube-api

I found a very useful tutorial on how to create a listview of youtube videos:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/

Then I followed another tutorial to make the videos in the listview clickable:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/

My problem is I do not want to play the videos with the youtube app - I would like to play them within MY app - so I created an instance of a youtube player:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/simple-example-using-youtube-android.html

My question is how can I modify my current onClick listener to pass the video's ID to my app's internal player instead of the youtube app during my onClick event?

```
onClick Listener (currently passing to standalone YouTube app):


    @Override
    public void onVideoClicked(Video video) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

### My Internal Youtube Player:

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

 public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCe6tORd9Ch4lx-9Ku5SQ476uS9OtZYsWA";
 public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
   YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "onInitializationFailure()", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
   boolean wasRestored) {
  if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
      }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
@Override
public void onVideoClicked(Video video) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); // Your youtubeplayer activity
    intent.putExtra("video_id",video_id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in `MainActivity` onCreate() you get the id and pass it to your Youtube player:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("video_id");
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not seem to work - so I took a step back and reverted my code to match the tutorial EXACTLY - but it seems I can't even get it to launch the Youtube app - care to take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476070/youtube-app-does-not-launch-onclick-as-expected